# Cximage project COMPILATION WITH vs2022

Tags: visual-c++

Can any one tell the what is the latest version of "Cximage"   that can work with VS 2022?
I downloaded cximage702_full.7z
But while running this, I got several errors and warnings.
Maybe the project properties were not corectly done in VS2022

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.